# Is there any way to display an erb submit_tag as disabled while required fields are empty?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, form-submit, erb

There was a :disabled_with (now deprecated) for disabling the button after submit, but the button should appear disabled until required fields are filled out in the first place.  Is there any way to do this beyond adding a bunch of javascript to validate the existence of data in any of the required fields?

Comment: use jquey validator http://jqueryvalidation.org

Comment: @Zaaferani, seconded.  I use that as a solution often.

Comment: jquery validator doesn't at all do what I wanted - which was to disable the submit button so the user doesn't even get to click it while fields are invalid.  I already have rails validation on click.  It also requires a significant amount of javascript - if I have a handful of forms, and have to specify rules for each individual field.

Answer (score 0):

If `disabled_with` is deprecated, can you not use the solutions suggested here?

`<%= submit_tag "Login", 'data-disable-with' => "Please wait.." %>`

`<%= submit_tag "Login", data: { disable_with: "Please wait.." } %>`

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/submit_tag

You could also change the `:disabled` value? once you've detected all the fields are filled?

Comment: This disables the submit button after it's been clicked

Answer (score 0):

What else you can do is on submit tag put a java script check which always check that required input fields are empty or have value and after all fields are filled with values then return true else false with message like `please fill the required fields`

Comment: Again, requiring a bunch of javascript to check each individual field